# How to display all articles on the website in Joomla! 3.8.7?

Tags: articles, layout

I have over 200 articles in this category but actually, on this page, it is displaying only the last 30 recent ones and also in a column format.

https://www.kiagia.com/index.php/bollywood-mobile/bollywood-movies-reviews/current-film-releases-movie

I would like to know how can I display all the articles in this category and to display them in two columns.

Can someone please help me with the instructions?

Apologies if this question has been repeated but I cannot find a similar question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those settings are in the menu item for the page.  If you do not have a menu item for that particular category, go ahead and make it and you can set Display In Menu = No.

The menu item should be a category blog for that category and you can set the columns and how many intro articles you want on the Options tab.